# how to override the derivative of a function ?

Tags: functions, function-construction

i have the following equation :

```
R = y \[Function] 
   Evaluate[
    Simplify@
     Piecewise[{{1.31446 Tan[1.58986 y] + 0.91209 y, 
        Abs[y] < 0.84136}, {1./(sign[y] - y), 
        0.841360 <= Abs[y] < 1.}}]];
```

how can i override the derivative of the function to be (R'[y_]:=) :

```
1./(1./R[y]^2 - 1./Sinh[R[y]]^2)
```

Comment: How about defining it as a new function (say `rd1[y_]=1./(1./R[y]^2 - 1./Sinh[R[y]]^2)`) and using it in your expression instead of `R'[y]`?

Comment: i know that it is possible with defining another function i just wanted to ask out of curiosity if it is possible to override the derivative with the same function ?

Comment: You can define the derivative ([see here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningDerivatives.html)) without defining the function. But once you define the function it would be overridden.